# How to determine if a ParameterInfo is a return parameter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection, parameterinfo

How can one determine if a `ParameterInfo` is a Return Parameter?

I wrote the function below, but I'm concerned that I may be missing something:

```
public bool IsReturnParameter(ParameterInfo parameter){
    var method = parameter.Member as MethodInfo;
    return method != null && parameter.Equals(method.ReturnParameter);
}
```

I am basing this on a couple assumptions, which may be flawed: (1) Parameters are declared on members that are `MethodInfo`, `ConstructorInfo` or `PropertyInfo` (indexers). (2) `ConstructorInfo` and `PropertyInfo` will never have a return parameter.

Comment: You want to know if the method has out/ref parameters?

Comment: No.  I want to know if it is a return parameter of the method

Comment: To be clear, you want the ParameterInfo which tells you if the return of the method has any custom attributes?

Comment: @JeffN825, Yes. That is what I am trying to test.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question.  What would usage for this be like?  The `ReturnParameter` value doesn't show up in the results of `GetParameters()`, based on my tests - the only way I've found to get at it is to explicitly check the `ReturnParameter` property.  And if you're doing that, you already know that it's the return parameter.

Comment: @Bobson, I'm crawling the type definition and I don't want to pass my visitor the container method of the parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check if the `ParameterInfo.Position == -1`...but your equality check seems equally as good...though it won't correctly handle overrides or interfaces or generic types in some cases.

Comment: Aww, I knew I was forgetting something

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're referring to `out int foo`, you want [`parameter.IsOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isout.aspx).

If you want the return value, try [`IsRetval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isretval.aspx), although I've never heard of that before.

Comment: (1) I am not asking for an out parameter.  I am asking for the return value.  (2) That is not what `IsRetval` is for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734607/when-are-parameterinfo-islcid-or-parameterinfo-isretval-true

Comment: So `IsRetval` **is** the correct thing to check, except that the compiler doesn't generally set it.  "`The [retval] attribute designates the parameter that receives the return value of the member.`"