# ParameterInfo properties, attributes and out ref parameters of the methods

Tags: c#, reflection, out, ref, parameterinfo

Well, I'm confused by the properties of the `ParameterInfo` class.
Unfortunately documentation is not very clear: examples show how to build methods but don't show how these methods look in C#.

Cane somebody tell more about these properties:

- `DefaultValue`
- `HasDefaultValue`
- `IsIn`
- `IsLcid`
- `IsOptional`
- `IsOut`
- `IsRetval`

And which combination leads to what method params.
I made a simple program which gives the following output:

*Method name M1* `void M1(object param)`
IL signature: `.method public hidebysig instance void  M1(object param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M2*  `void M2(object param = null)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M2([opt] object param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
**HasDefaultValue=True**
DefaultValue=null
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
**IsOptional=True**
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M3* `void M3(out object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M3([out] object& param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed **by reference True**
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
**IsOut=True**
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M4* `void M4(ref object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M4(object& param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed **by reference True**
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M5* `void M5([In] object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M5([in] object param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
HasDefaultValue=False
**IsIn=True**
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M6* `void M6([Out] object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M6([out] object param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
**IsOut=True**
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M7* `void M7([Out] out object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M7([out] object& param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed **by reference True**
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
**IsOut=True**
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M8* `void M8([DefaultValue(null)] object param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M8(object param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
IsOptional=False
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M9* `void M9([DefaultValue(-10)] int param = 10)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M9([opt] int32 param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Parameter name param
Is passed by reference False
**HasDefaultValue=True**
DefaultValue=10
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
**IsOptional=True**
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False


*Method name M10* `void M10([Optional] int param)`
IL signature `.method public hidebysig instance void  M10([opt] int32 param) cil managed`
Method parameter description:
Is passed by reference False
HasDefaultValue=False
IsIn=False
IsLcid=False
**IsOptional=True**
IsOut=False
IsRetVal=False

I guess `In`, `Out` and `Optional` attributes relate to COM as they are located in System.Runtime.InteropServices namesapce.
But again documentation is quite poor. :(

And what is RetVal and where it is used?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734607/when-are-parameterinfo-islcid-or-parameterinfo-isretval-true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows most of them, including the optional, out and defaultvalue flags. Note that the return value can be represented as a `ParameterInfo` because it shares most things in common with parameters, including attributes (via the `[return: Foo]` syntax). For retval and lcid, see [When are ParameterInfo.IsLcid or ParameterInfo.IsRetval true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734607/when-are-parameterinfo-islcid-or-parameterinfo-isretval-true)

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test");

        Describe(method.ReturnParameter);
        foreach (var p in method.GetParameters()) Describe(p);
    }
    static void Describe(ParameterInfo param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Name) ? "(no name)" : param.Name,
            param.ParameterType, param.Position);
        if (param.IsRetval) Console.WriteLine("retval");
        if (param.IsIn) Console.WriteLine("in");
        if (param.IsOut) Console.WriteLine("out");
        if (param.ParameterType.IsByRef) Console.WriteLine("by-ref");
        if (param.IsOptional) Console.WriteLine("optional");
        if (param.HasDefaultValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("default value: {0}", param.DefaultValue);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static int Test(int j, ref int k, out int l, string foo = "abc")
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```